# Subquery en una consulta linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

como convertir esta query en una linq

```
select 
    e.cod,
    e.Nombre,
    c.FechaRegistro,
    Uso = (select  sum(Valor) from incidente i where i.CodEntidad = c.CodEntidad),
    Fondo = (select  sum(Valor) from Fondo i where i.CodEntidad = c.CodEntidad)

from Cobertura c 
inner join Entidad e on e.IdEntidad = c.CodEntidad
where c.Estado = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FUENTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/lt-lt/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-a-subquery-on-a-grouping-operation)

```
(from c in db.Cobertura
join e in db.Entidad on c.CodEntidad equals e.IdEntidad
where c.Estado == true
select new
{
    Uso = (from i in db.Incidente where i.CodEntidad == c.CodEntidad select i.Valor).Sum(),
    Fondo = (from f in db.Fondo where f.CodEntidad == c.CodEntidad select f.Valor).Sum()

}).ToList();
```